How to to change the value for a key in an array in PHP?
<?php

    $orderTracking = $order['ItemDetails'][0]['TrackingDetails'] ?? [];
    $tracking = []; //Declaration of the array
    foreach ($orderTracking as $track) {
        if (is_array($track)) {
            $tracking[] = array_unique($track); //Initially assigned value
        }
    }

    $customerNumber = str_pad($block->getSAPAccountNumber() ?? '', 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) ?? '';

    $trNumbers = [];
    $trData = [];

    foreach ($tracking as $track) {
        if (!in_array($track['trackingNumber'] ?? [], $trNumbers)) {
            $trNumbers[] = $track['trackingNumber'] ?? [];
            if (strlen($track['trackingNumber'] ?? '') > 1) {
                $track['trackingURL'] = $block->createTrackingURL($track['carrier'], $track['trackingNumber']);  //Value of this key has to be changed which is not changing
                $trData[$order['ItemDetails'][0]['itemNo']] = $track;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>

I want to change the value for 'trackingURL' key whose value will be given by the createTrackingURL function. But the the value is not changing even after assigning.
What is the reason ?

Use foreach ($tracking as &$track) { (added &), so that modification of $track are written to the original array.
